# unable to submit message: The path is not of a legal form

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, api, filepath

I have only frontend code which works with API calls. I need to implement a similar page for photos with changing some parameters like job type, preference name, etc. When I changed job type=2, it always showed this error. I checked API with job type 2 on postman, It is working fine but not in the code and app.so what might be the error.for example,
     SendNewJob: function (e) {

```
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#inputValidationErrorMessage").hide();
    $("#extRefValidationErrorMessage").hide();
    var existingToken = IO.LocalStorage.GetValue("userToken");

    var frmData1 = new FormData();

    var model = {
        ThirdPartyClientId: Number($("#thirdPartyUser1").val()) || undefined,
        JobType: 2,
        Reference: $("#jobRefNr1").val(),
        Notes: $("#notes").val(),
        ExternalReference: $("#externalRefNr1").val() || undefined,
        PreferenceNameId: Number($("#prefernceTypePhoto").val()) || undefined
    };
```

and
    service.js file

```
var ProjectConfigurationLevel =
{
Debug: 0,
Local: 1,
Live: 2
};

var FloorplanType =
{
Sketch: 1,
Draft: 2,
Ammendments: 3,
Final: 4
};

var MessageType =
{
Redirect: 0,
Info: 1,
Warning: 2,
Error: 3
};

var ForFront = {

Config: ProjectConfigurationLevel.Live,

Defaults: {
    JobsPageSize: 5,
    MaxPagesShown: 5
},

Urls: {
    Live: "https://api.xyz.com/",
    Debug: "http://test-api.xyz.com/",
    Local: "http://192.168.60.75:3000/",
},

Links: {
    SketchLocation: function () {
        switch (ForFront.Config) {
            case ProjectConfigurationLevel.Debug:
                return "http://testsite.com/";
            case ProjectConfigurationLevel.Local:
                return "http://192.168.60.75:3001/";
            case ProjectConfigurationLevel.Live:
                return "http://testsite.com/";
            default:
                console.error("unknown config " + ForFront.Config);
                break;
        }
    },
```

SubmitNewJob: function () {
            var endpoint = "v1/Jobs";

Comment: what is the error

Comment: You haven’t shown any code so we can’t tell.

Comment: for changing job type 2 it is showing "the path is not of a legal form" after submitting.